# Set datetime measure unit in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I setup my column chart with 3 data points. Each x value is a datetime value - different hour within one day.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        series: [{
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0), 1], 
                [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 1, 2, 0, 0), 1], 
                [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 1, 4, 0, 0), 1]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

This is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/CqkUc/1/

My problem is that every column tooltip shows the same date, and i want them to show different hours. I know that i can use the tooltip formatter function, but i think there might be a way to force xAxis unit to be an hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the formatting for each level of a dateTime axis and tooltip.  The axis format is different than the tooltip format by default.  See http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip and http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats for the default values. It appears to be using the day format for those data points in the tooltip, though I'm not sure why.  It makes sense for the 1st one which has all 0s for it's time element, but not for the others.

http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/CqkUc/2/

```
  $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        tooltip: {
            dateTimeLabelFormats : {
                day: '%H:%M',
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: '%H:%M'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0), 1],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 1, 2, 0, 0), 1],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 1, 4, 0, 0), 1]
            ]
        }]
    });
```

Comment: I change my data dynamically. It can be months within a year, days within a month and hours within a day. In most of the cases the tooltip shows what I suppose to see. But when I have time 0:00 it shows me dates instead of times. I hope that it's not necessary to set tooltip format every time manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tooltip formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) and [dateFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat%28%29) to customise the time which is displayed.